# accessing specific page with some criteria in opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I have a specific information page (page id is 12) and from admin panel i have assigned this page ID to particular product. For example, Information-id 12 is assigned to to Product1. When a user buys that product, and when the order status is set to 'Complete', user should have access to that page(information-id). I mean , to access this page, user should buy that product and order status is to be complete and user should logged in.

I am not getting how to do it. In order.tpl, i tried doing like this, but if i copy the URL and paste , it can be accessible without logging in.

here is my order_list.tpl

```
$end_date= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date. ' + '.$date1. 'days'));

       echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($end_date));
        ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="history">Product Name</td>
       <?php $today = date('Y-m-d'); ?>

       <?php if(($order['status']='Complete') AND ($today > $end_date))  { ?>
        <td><strong><h4><font color="#FF0000">Either Your Course date is Expired or Order is not completed!!</font></h4></strong> </td> 
        <?php } 
        else { ?>
       <td><a href="<?php echo $order['href1']; ?>"><strong><?php echo $order['pname']; ?></strong></a></td>
       <?php } ?>
      </tr>
```

Here i am also checking the expiry date, which am capturing through admin.

If i put `customer_islogged()`, in information.php(controller), i cannot access any other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function where you can pass list of products, any of that needs to be purchased to access that particular page

```
//catalog/model/account/order.php

   public function checkForAccess($product_id_list){
        $exists = false;
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT product_id FROM ".DB_PREFIX."order o LEFT JOIN ".DB_PREFIX."order_product op ON (o.order_id=op.order_id) WHERE o.order_status_id=5 AND o.customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() ."'");
        foreach($query->rows as $product){
            if(in_array($product['product_id'],$product_id_list)){
                $exists = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $exists;
    }
```

Now in that particular page you can check if the customer has completed purchased or not

```
$this->load->model('account/order');
//Eg Customer will have access who have purchased product 20 and 22         
$product_list = array(20,22);
$results = $this->model_account_order->checkForAccess($product_list);

if(!$results){
    //where to redirect if not valid
    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('common/home'));
}
```